# In tab layout activity my fragment does not refresh while swiping

Tags: android, fragment

I'm using fragmentpageradapter to inflate fragment , this is my coding.
i'm adding cart item in one fragment and showing it to other fragment and all fragment comes in tab layout.My problem is cart item is not refreshing on other fragment while swiping fragment.

```
public class ProfileDetailePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
   {
    int TabCount;
    HashMap<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public ProfileDetailePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int TabCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.TabCount = TabCount;
        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                MenuFragment tab1 = new MenuFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                SelectMember_fragment tab2 = new SelectMember_fragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                ViewCart_fragment tab3 = new ViewCart_fragment();
                return tab3;
          /*  case 3:
                PaymentMode_fragment tab4=new PaymentMode_fragment();
                return tab4;*/
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TabCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
            // record the fragment tag here.
            Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
            String tag = f.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return obj;
    }


    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag == null)
            return null;
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are extending FargmentPagerAdapter intead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: @farhana yes yes . One of the reason .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Call **`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`**
- You should use **[addOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#addOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener))**

> This method is used to add a  listener that will be invoked when tab
>   selection changes.

```
tabLayoutOBJ.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
            String getTAB = (String)tab.getText();
            // Do your WORK 

        }
        public void  onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind it is the implementation of viewpager. There is a property called offset in ViewPager to make ready fragments next to it up to offset(int) value.

Default value is 1. For example, you are in 1st position, 0th and 2nd positions are also created.

On the other hand if you are in 0th position 1st is the only created fragment. If you swipe to right (going 1st) then 2nd is going to be created.

I assume you are changing a shared object from 1st fragment and want to notify 2nd fragment with changed data. To solve it you need to use listener. The elegant way to solve it is adding observer pattern to your shared object.

Good luck

Emre